# Using specific strings in a text file as a variable in a batch process

Tags: csv, batch-file, batch-processing, gdal

I am writing a batch file that processes an image using an external toolkit based off an existing image (`%%t`), querying a text file with columns of data for a specific value, and then feeding the queried data back into the batch process as new command criteria.  My code is as follows:

```
for /r %%t in (*.tif) do (

    cd /d C:\Program Files\Allegorithmic\Substance Automation Toolkit
    sbsrender.exe render -v --input "C:\Program Files\Allegorithmic\Substance Automation Toolkit\test.sbsar" --set-entry input@"%%t" --output-path "C:\Users\Dave\Desktop\Substance" --output-format jpg --output-name "%%~nt"

    cd C:\Users\Dave\Desktop\Substance
    for /f "tokens=1-5 delims= " %%a in (C:\Users\Dave\Desktop\sectors.txt) do (
        if "%%e"=="%%~nt" (
            gdal_translate -of JPEG -co QUALITY=81 -a_ullr %%a %%b %%c %%d %%~nt.jpg %%~nt%-1.jpg
        )
    )
)

pause
```

An important aspect need to be in place - the name of the file generated in the first place has to be preserved as criteria for the query of the text file (`%%~nt`), as it will be this value that specifies the coordinates to supply to the `gdal_translate` command:

> 598000 5728000 602000 5724000 19

I am querying off this final value in the last column, because it should match the filename referenced in the very first line of code.  The source `tif` files correspond with rows in the text file.  For this to work, `"%%e"` should equal `"%%~nt"`.  It has to be returning the coordinates for the correct sector.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Some syntax issues are the opening parentheses expected to be on the same line as the `if`, else a syntax error happens. Is missing a closing parentheses as well. If those are fixed, what is the actual problem? as I tested and got a evaluated result of `if "19" == "19" (` using a target file named `19.tif`.

Comment: I am still having issues.  The command window appears and closes immediately, probably because there is a syntax issue with the script.  I have added opening and closing parentheses on the `if` line, but it's still not working.  

`(
for /f "tokens=1, 2, 3, 4, 5 delims= " %%a IN (C:\Users\Dave\Desktop\sectors.txt) DO 
 (if "%%e"=="%%~nt" )
 gdal_translate -of JPEG -co QUALITY=81 -a_ullr %%a %%b %%c %%d %%~nt.jpg %%~nt%-1.jpg
    
)
)
pause`

Comment: Ok, I have figured it out.  I eventually corrected my parentheses structure by looking at these two links:

https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-brackets.html
https://ss64.com/nt/for.html

Thanks.

Comment: I fixed some minor issues in your posted code. If the problem still exist, please inform of what it is.